# How to add definition QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT in a CMake file?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am using ROS, therefore writing CMake files.
In Qt `.pro` file, we can use:

```
DEFINE+=QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
```

How can we do that in a CMake file? I tried:

```
add_definitions(QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT)
```

but it gives me the following error:

> c++: error: QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT: No such file or directory

Comment: Try this add_definition(-DQT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`add_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) requires you to write your flags according to the compiler syntax: in your case with `-D` (would be `/D` on visual). You should just write:

```
add_definitions(-DQT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT)
```

A more flexible, fine-grained approach is to add definitions per target with [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html):

```
add_executable(foo ...)
target_compile_definitions(foo PUBLIC QT_DEBUG_NO_OUTPUT)
```

Note that you don't need the `-D` here.